# How to select fields on different indents in json output

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-requests, field

I am trying to pull two fields in a JSON output that are on different indents. How can I select them both and output them back to me?

Example of JSON data:

```
],
    "hostName": "Test123",
    "hostNames": [
        {
            "name": "Test",
            "source": "other"
        },
        {
            "name": "Test",
            "source": "other"
        }
    ],
    "id": 123,
    "ids": [
        {
            "id": "111",
            "source": "none"
        },
```

Example of the code I tried to use:

```
    for i in data["hostName", "id"]:
        print(i)
```

Error:

```
KeyError: ('hostName', 'id')
```

There are multiple ID fields but I would only like the one where the id is 123, these ids will vary so I cannot hard-code it to search for id = 123. Instead I need it to reference the specific indent where id is 123 in this example.

The output should be something like:

```
hostName : Test123,  id : 123
```

Comment: The data shown isn't well-formed JSON.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi there i made it better formatted. does this help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to show us the full JSON you're trying to parse, because the from the first 2 characters it doesn't look like well-formed JSON `],`.

You need to either delete everything in the json above that, or find the value before the `hostname` and do this,

```
for i in data[1]["hostName", "id"]:
       print(i)
```

where `1` is the number of the nested list your JSON appears to be in.